# Is it implied that the werewolf is one of them?

Tags: an-american-werewolf-in-london

When the two travelers are in the pub, not only is the pub marked by a pentagram but everyone seems aware of the danger that the boys are subject to -- they are warned to stick to the roads, stay off the moors but certainly not told explicitly what they will face.

I got the impression, but I am sure it is not clearly stated, that the monster that attacks David and kills his friend is not only known to the locals but may be one of them. Perhaps someone who lives sort of like a homeless person who is not pursued by locals and in exchange preys only on strangers.

Is there a novelization or commentary by the director/writer about the relationship between the locals and the monster?

And if the werewolf is known to them, does the attitude of the locals reflect the tacit conspiracy to sacrifice these two strangers -- strangers who perhaps the locals preferred were not very young people just embarking upon life?

EDIT: An interesting thought (to me) is that perhaps the werewolf is actually one of the customers in the pub. The dart thrower and the opponent of the joke teller in the chess game seem like possible candidates. However, it is neither of them and we later get a glimpse of the dead werewolf after it turns human again -- not sure if we can find him earlier in the pub.

Comment: Can only find an unsubstantiated note online that states the werewolf was a previous member of the "Werewolf Society",  It's been a long time since I watched the film so I'm not sure if the "Werewolf Society" was the people in the Slaughtered Lamb or not?  The statement is made on https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Werewolf_(An_American_Werewolf_in_London) in the trivia section about a deleted scene....

Comment: @Alith one wonders indeed what The Werewolf Society might be. The people we see in the pub simply seem to be sad, secretive individuals who have no love of werewolves but rather are dealing with one (who could be a local) in the best way they can and perhaps the attack on two young strangers was the straw that broke the camel's back. The werewolf might have been someone's son, maybe the joke teller's, and he resisted killing him until the attack occurred.

Comment: Indeed, it could be that the regulars of the pub, formed the "Werewolf Society" to deal with the werewolf, but as you say, if the werewolf was known to them, maybe they didn't want to do anything until David and Jack were attacked?

Comment: @Alith: The BBC made a radio dramatization: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQapRY8Uzvg which seems to have stuff not in the movie -- so far, the werewolf is apparently an inmate in a mental institution. I will listen on, see if there is some explanations of questions raised. Jenny Agutter is in both flick and this.